# Submitting a suggested edit for a tag, still results in a "Tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?"

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign

This is a bug, because an "edit" (at least to the extent that the user can make it) has already been made.

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to change this, perhaps for the first few days of the private beta reducing the rep that is required to review tag wiki edits?

Comment: VTCd, this is already resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It already is reduced. Normally it's 5k or something. It's now 750--someone's bound to reach that level soon.

Wait for the SE people to chose pro tempore mods. In the meantime, I think the SE team members will be roaming around the site fulfilling moderation roles.

Though this is still a bug, since suggested edits are fully visible to the editor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you just created the tag wiki *body* (i.e., not the *excerpt*).

Because all of the tag wikis here are blank, your tag wiki will not be shown until you (or someone else) have *also* created the tag wiki excerpt. However, the next editor will see your body when they go to create the tag wiki excerpt.

See also [this answer on the global Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki/80153#80153).

The best practice is probably to create both of them at the same time.

Comment: That is not the case. I created both. Adding printscreen to question.